# How do specify different class priors while using caret package?

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

In R, rpart function allows me to set different class priors through 'parms'. How do I set this while using the train function in caret?

Answer (score 0):

You include it inside `train` function.

As example:

```
library("caret")

train(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis, method = "rpart",
          parms = list(prior = c(0.65, 0.35)))
```